# Sql Server 2008 Database Project Delta Deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have created a new Sql 2008 Database Project in Visual Studio 2010.  I imported the database objects and only kept the stored procedures.  That all worked as expected.  Where I have the problem is that it tries to deploy the entire set of procedures each time.  I expect it to only create the deployment script for the delta.  I am pretty sure that I combed every setting, but I can't find it.  So if someone could first validate that this is possible and second tell me where to look. I need to do this because we only deploy the stored procedures with each release, the database schema is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Schema compare of the project (as source) with the database where you want to deploy (as target). Once shcem comparison results are shown you have a choice to select which changes you want to deploy and then click the button "Export to T-SQL Editor". It will create the delta script.